# Adding custom validation logic to dart:io HttpClient

Tags: http, flutter, dart, client, httpclient

I am trying to create an [HttpClient](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html) that can validate an SSL certificate after every TLS handshake and before any other data is fetched/sent.

So the flow would look like this:

1. Create an HttpClient
2. Execute a request
3. The client connects to the host via HTTPS
4. After the TLS handshake was done, the client now knows the certificate
5. Pass the certificate to a callback. Execute actual request when callback succeeds, abort the request otherwise
6. In case the callback was successful, proceed as usual (e.g. pass the response etc.)

I was looking into [SecurityContext](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/SecurityContext-class.html) already. The problem is that it only validates against a fixed set of certificates, but I want to validate the certificate dynamically based on the certificate that was sent by the host.
Also, I saw that there is a [badCertificateCallback](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/HttpClient/badCertificateCallback.html) method in HttpClient, but this does not serve my usecase well as I want to validate every certificate, not just the invalid/bad ones.

I was wondering whether I could theoretically create a class that uses HttpClient as a superclass and therefore modify it's behaviour, but I am wondering whether there is a more elegant way that doesn't break that easily when the implementation of HttpClient changes.

Another idea of mine is to set a SecurityContext that rejects every single certificate by default. I could then use the badCerificateCallback to do the checks normally done by SecurityContext (check against a list of trusted certificates) and add my own validation on top of that. Is anyone aware of any drawbacks this might have? I got a little bit uncertain when reading about the [limitations regarding iOS](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/SecurityContext-class.html).

Has anyone here done similar things before and could give me a hint? :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For your usecase, it is better that you have your own version of `BetterHttpClient`.

However, instead of `BetterHttpClient` inheriting from `HttpClient`, you can use composition. Compose `HttpClient` inside `BetterHttpClient`. This will give you more control over what you want to use/update from the existing implementation and also this will be better guarded against any changes that `HttpClient` will go through